# Is there any way to setup a 3TB SATA drive in Windows XP?

Tags: hard-drive, windows-xp, partitioning, dynamic-disk, dell-optiplex

I have a [Dell OptiPlex GX520](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/product-support/product/optiplex-gx520/manuals) PC and I want to setup [Western Digital 3 TB](http://www.wdc.com/en/products/products.aspx?id=760#Tab3) (dynamic disk) in my PC.

But it reads only 700 GB from Windows XP although it read 3TB from the setup screen of my Dell. The problem is I can’t format it or do anything.

I want to partition the hard disk to two partitions: 70 gb for the Windows XP, and the other for my data but how?

Comment: Yes;  But since Windows XP does not support booting to GPT it will be impossible to use more then the (Windows) limits of MBR partitions.  It basically involves loading a driver there are countless partitioning applications that do that.

Comment: why don't just install Linux?

Answer (score 3):

I don’t believe that Windows XP can handle 3TB drives, but [according to this article in *PC World*](http://www.pcworld.idg.com.au/review/seagate/barracuda_3tb_st3000dm001_internal_hard_drive/427323/):

> If you want to use the 3TB Barracuda on a Windows XP system, then you
>   will need to run Seagate's [DiskWizard](http://www.seagate.com/support/internal-hard-drives/enterprise-hard-drives/savvio-15k/discwizard-master-dl) program to make the drive usable
>   under that operating system.

Now I know you have a Western Digital drive—and that solution refers to a Seagate specific tool—but the general message is: Windows XP won’t normally handle large capacity drives like that right out of the box. And looking [the Western Digital white paper on “Large Capacity Drives”](http://www.wdc.com/wdproducts/library/WhitePapers/ENG/2579-771501.pdf), they state:

> **Limitations of 512-byte Sector Size**
>
> Older operating systems such as the Windows® XP computing environment
>   with a legacy BIOS and Master Boot Record (MBR) partition table scheme
>   encounter a barrier at 2.19 TB because they can address only up to 232
>   logical blocks x (sector size) capacity and the most commonly used
>   sector size is 512 bytes. Do the math and you get a capacity
>   limitation of 2.19 TB (2,199,023,255,552 bytes). Some operating
>   systems, such as Windows XP, only support booting from an MBR (Master
>   Boot Record) partition formatted drive; therefore, there are
>   limitations when attempting to move to a higher capacity drive. The
>   system’s BIOS and operating system drivers need to agree on capacity
>   and geometry of a hard drive to boot and operate correctly. Agreement
>   must take place across several software layers to successfully boot a
>   system.
>
> **WD Provides Solutions for Moving Beyond 512-byte Sector Size (Greater than 2.19 TB)**
>
> WD initially led the way in providing solutions for drives larger than
>   2.19 TB which included a Host Bus Adapter with our 2.5 TB and 3 TB hard drives. This HBA is no longer being provided, and is not needed
>   as updated storage drivers and system software with support for large
>   capacity drives are now available. WD also worked collectively with
>   industry partners, system providers, and operating system vendors to
>   ensure drive compatibility across multiple software layers. Support
>   for drives larger than the current 2.19 TB capacity barrier means
>   implementing these solutions to successfully integrate high capacity
>   drives.

Also, [this page—titled “Resolve 748 GB limitation for the hard disk over 2, 3 tera (2TB, 3TB)”—seems to have more detailed info](http://post-anything-here.blogspot.fr/2015/02/resolve-748-gb-limitation-for-hard-disk.html) on how to resolve the issue.

Comment: is the problem from the windows xp or my pc as a hardware ?
is it possible to format and parition the hd from another windows 7 pc then use the hd disk as a secondary disk with the whole capacity ?
what does `dynamic disk` mean ?